# Remote Debug desktop app visual studio 2015

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, desktop-application

I used to develop and remote debug one device creating Windows Store Apps with VS 2013 for Windows.

Now I am using a Microsoft VS Community 2015 (v 14..) and I created a Windows Desktop App using WPF,
but I cant remote debug anymore but only running with/out debug.

Please how can I remote debug a desktop app with VS2015?

I tried with this [msdn tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx) but when I run my app it shows a message like this:

*"error in trying to execute the project: Impossible to start debugging. The debugger is not able to connect to remote computer. Impossible to solve the specified computer name"*

Comment: Have you tried [this link?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx)

Comment: I tried with your link and add more info

Comment: Hsve you tried with an ip instead of a hostname? - seems like it cannot resolve the hostname

Comment: now it says that MSVMON.exe is not running but actually I started the remote debugger. it is the same that I used for VS2013

Comment: after installing the new remote tool for VS 2015, It seems to kind of work but it does not stop to breakpoints..do u know why?

Comment: Hmm usually because of missing pdb files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89284/discussion-between-eeadev-and-visualbean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "error in trying to execute the project: Impossible to start debugging. The debugger is not able to connect to remote computer. Impossible to solve the specified computer name"

### Here's what went down in the chat;

- First of Try using an IP address instead of a hostname.
- @eeadev then installed a new version of the remote debugger which resulted in it working, but no breakpoints were hit.
- I  told @eeadev to move the contents of the debug folder to the remote server , because of the ties with the pdb file for debugging.
- After @eeadev did the above, everything worked. happy days!